# Recurly validation error "Name is invalid."

Tags: recurly

I'm trying to use the Recurly php client library to integrate the service into a PHP platform and I'm running into an error that doesn't seem to make sense.
I am calling  recurly api version 2.29. When i call the subscription or purchase api i get validation error  "Name is invalid.". Though i tried passing all name fields that were possible. Has anyone faced this error. Please help.

Comment: Please post the code to your API call (redact keys)

Comment: You question is vague. You may be attempting to call methods that do not correspond to the API version you are using. I suggest you use the [current API](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-php) and reference the documentation [here](https://developers.recurly.com/api/v2021-02-25/index.html)